# Trim the end of n-th column unix

Tags: sed, awk

I have  table structure:

> ous.txt 1452 1793
>
> out.txt 36796 14997
>
> ouw.txt 478
>   4247

3 columns & lots of rows.

I want to trim ".txt" - last 4 characters from the #1 column (with awk, sed).

I know that chopping the end of line was covered times here, but i don't know how to access the end of n-th collumn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your sample input, this would do it:

```
sed 's/\.txt//' filename
```

If I only wanted to operate on the 1st whitespace-delimted column, I'd use awk or just the shell:

```
while read -r col1 col2 col3; do
    printf "%s %s %s\n" "${col1%.txt}" "$col2" "$col3"
done < filename
```

Comment: Or in the general case of "last four non-tab characters before the first tab", `s/[^\t][^\t][^\t][^\t]\t/\t/` (where you would substitute a literal tab for `\t` if your `sed` doesn't understand this convenient representation).  Creful, though; if you have lines where the first field is less than four characters, you will get unexpected results.  (Maybe anchor the expression then; `s/^\([^\t]*\)[^\t][^\t][^\t][^\t]\t/\t/`.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the last 4 characters of column 1:

```
awk '{sub(/....$/, "", $1)} 1' filename
```

If the columns are separated by spaces, but not tabs:

```
sed 's/.... / /' filename
```